# libGDX - How to stop player's movement at a specific position?

Tags: java, vector, libgdx, position

I'll try to explain what i need to achieve.

My player starts at 0, 0 position.
When I touch the screen, the player starts to move up. 
And when the player is at the specific position in the Y axis (Let's say 200), I want him to stop moving.

When I touch the screen this method is called:

```
    public void move() {
    if (player.getPosition().y < 200) {
        player.velocity.set(0, 100);
    }
```

And in my player's update method I have:

```
        if (player.getPosition().y > 200) {
        player.position.set(0, 200);
        player.velocity.set(0, 0);
    }
```

The problem with this is that if I set the velocity in the move method to something like 1000, there is one frame rendered with the position of the player above 200. Then it changes it to 200 and stays there.

I tried this in the update method:

```
if (player.getPosition().y == 200) {
player.velocity.set(0, 0);
```

}

But this statement is never true because the position of the player is always 200 and some random numbers like 200.1257 or 200.54578

I will appreciate all your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to an integer like this:

```
if ((int)player.getPosition().y == 200) {
    player.velocity.set(0, 0);
}
```

But i will not recommend it because if your player is at high speed it could skip the 200 and go on, i think the right thing to do is

```
if (player.getPosition().y > 200) {
      player.velocity.set(0, 0);
      player.setPosition(new Vector2(player.getX,200));
}
```

You can predict where your player are going and calculate the deacceleration as well for a smooth feel for the player..

Now if you want multiple vectors on screen the best is to calculate a distance between the player and the points on screen like this:

```
//If the player is 20 units closer than the point 200,200 do something
    if(player.getPosition().dst2(new Vector2(200,200) < 20){
      //do something
    }
```